# button needs two clicks to collapse a div in html angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a list of divs grouped with expand and collapse functionality like below. It works fine, except i need to click button twice to open another div. The first click only collapses first div.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
      <button
        (click)="setIndex(i)"
      >
        <span
          [translate]=“item.title”
        ></span>

      </button>
      <div
        [class.collapse]='currentIndex !== i'
      >
        <div [innerHTML]=“item.description | translate"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <hr>

    </div>
```

And I have my typescript function looks like below.

```
setIndex(i) {
    this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex === -1 ? i : -1;
  }
```

I tried changing click event to mousedown or keydown but it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using this logic: `this.currentIndex === -1 ? i : -1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `setIndex` function by:

```
setIndex(i) {
   this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex === i ? -1 : i;
}
```

Because the first click sets the `currentIndex` to `-1` so it collapses the first div *(because `currentIndex` is know different from all `i` values)* but you need it to be `i` *(the newly clicked `i`)* to also display the new div.

And if the div is currently displayed and you click on it again, *(so `currentIndex === i`)* we set it to `-1` so it collapses.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `setIndex()` like below.

### Explanation

We have declare `currentIndex = -1`.

When a user clicks on any button we have to check `currentIndex` if that is -1 we have to set a value of `i` in `currentIndex`.

Now more 2 option we have. If a user clicks on the same button, again and again, we have to check `i === currentIndex`

Last one if the first div is open so `currentIndex = 0`, Now a user clicks on the third button so `index is 2` Now First we have to set `currentIndex = -1 and currentIndex = i`

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data1; let i = index">
      <button (click)="setIndex(i)">
        <span>{{item.title}}</span>
      </button>
      <div [hidden]='currentIndex !== i'>
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

### ts

```
setIndex(i) {
    if (this.currentIndex === -1) {
        this.currentIndex = i;
    } else if (this.currentIndex === i) {
        this.currentIndex = i;
    } else {
        this.currentIndex = -1;
        this.currentIndex = i;
    }
}
```

### Note:

Here I use `[hidden]` just for example. You can use yours

Comment: Your `setIndex` function doesn't really make sense. Why assign a variable twice in a row? Why assign `i` to a variable that already contains this value?

Comment: Last case is different. first you click on 0th row so currentIndex have 0 now you click on 3rd row so currentIndex have still 0 because still you are going to assign value from last else condition because first 2 condition gets wrong